# Best way to choose a threshold for a multiclass classification problem

Tags: keras, deep-learning, threshold, multiclass-classification

I have build a model using Keras. My main aim is to classify animals belonging to 10 different categories. The model is performing well. However, when I am testing the images with non animal images, the model is trying to fit the image between the 10 different categories. That is if I test the model with a non animal image I am getting an animal as output with a high confidence score. I know that to solve this issue I must use a threshold. But I have not found any resource on how to do this task. Can someone help please?